# How to correct displaying value in chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devextreme

I am creating a circular gauge with devextreme in my ReactJS project. There is a problem with displaying some values.
For example value is 5011480286.78 but in the gauge it's displaying as 5.01E+9.
I don't want that. How can I fixed it?

```
<BarGauge
    id="gauge"
     startValue={0}
     endValue={max_value}
     baseValue={min_value}
     values={arr}
     palette="Soft Pastel">
     <Size height={300} width={300} />
     <Legend
         visible={true}
         customizeText={customizeText(labelval)}
         verticalAlignment="bottom"
         horizontalAlignment="center"
         />
 </BarGauge>
```

[image: example]

Comment: add type as `type = "largeNumber"`

Comment: Add ` format={}` in "Legend"

Comment: @groovy_guy to where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Label` component along with `format` props to handle how the notation of the value of the different guages look. Also you are using `customizeText` props in the `Legend` component incorrectly.

```
const format = {
  type: 'fixedPoint',
  precision: 1,
};
```

Here is the complete code: https://codesandbox.io/s/lqypl